# Aligning Custom SWR Hook Return Type with Expected Type

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm using swr and attempting to develop a block hook creator with generics. This creator should take mapParamsToKey and request methods as inputs and produce an SWR hook function. However, the return type of my custom hook, SWRResponse, does not align with the expected type. Here's the sample code I've written for reference.

```js
import useSWR from 'swr';

type Params = {
  id: number;
};
type BlogPost = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
};

const mapParamsToKey = (params: Params) => ['blog-post', params.id];
const request = (params: Params): Promise<BlogPost> => {
  const data = { id: params.id, title: `Blog Post ${params.id}` };
  return Promise.resolve(data);
};

const useBlogPost = (params: Params) =>
  useSWR(mapParamsToKey(params), () => request(params)); 
// (params: Params) => SWRResponse<BlogPost, any, any>


// swr hooks creator
function createBlockHook<P, T = any>(config: {
  mapParamsToKey: (params: P) => Array<string | number>;
  request: (params: P) => Promise<T>;
}) {
  return (params: P) =>
    useSWR(config.mapParamsToKey(params), () => config.request(params));
}

const useBlogPost2 = createBlockHook<Params>({
  mapParamsToKey,
  request,
}); 
// (params: Params) => SWRResponse<any, any, any>
// SWRResponse data type is any, but `BlogPost` is expected (infer from `request` param)
```

Expected usage scenario:

```js
import client from './my-api-client';
type CommentParams = { id: number; } 
const useComment = createBlockHook<CommentParams>({
  mapParamsToKey: (params) => ['comment', params.id], 
  request: client.getComment, // (params: CommentParams) => Promise<Comment>
}); 

function Comment(props: { id: number }) {
  const swr = useComment(props); 
  if (swr.data) {
    // swr.data with type hint `Comment`
    return (
      <div>{swr.data.content}</div>
    )
  }
  return <div>...</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, you want to type the input and the output of `useSWR` with your API.
We managed to do that with a code similar to this:

```js
type RestApi = {
  'posts/{postId}/comments': {
    input: { postId: string },
    output: { comments: Comment[] }
  },
  // ...

}

export function useApi<E extends keyof RestApi>(
  endpointKey: E | null | undefined | false,
  params?: Partial<RestApi[E]['input']>,
  options?: SWRConfiguration,
) {
  return useSWR<RestApi[E]['output'], HTTPError>(
    endpointKey && [endpointKey, params],
    fetcher,
    options,
  );
}
```

You can type your API in `RestApi` and use `useApi('posts/{postId}/comments', {postId})`.
You will have to write your fetcher accordingly and your output will be properly typed.

Comment: Yes, quite similar concept. But my api client already has "typed" response.   `createBlockHook<CommentParams, Comment>({ mapParamsToKey, request })` works find. but I want to find a way without manually entering the "output" type,   `createBlockHook<CommentParams>({ mapParamsToKey, request })` as the request params from my api client already has "typed"  `Promise<Comment>`.